# Im studying polymorphism and ran into a problem

Tags: c++, class, vector, polymorphism

I created an abstract base class with two sub classes:

```
class Base {
public: 
    int a, b, c;
    virtual void unreal() = 0; 
};

class Sub1: public Base {
public:
    virtual void unreal() {}
};

class Sub2: public Base {
public:
    virtual void unreal() {}
};
```

I want to create a function that I can pass parameter of both types:

```
vector<Sub1> v1 and vector<Sub2> v2
```

into it, using something like:

```
Function(vector<Base&> v) {}
```

But it didn't work. So I want to know is there anyway to do it?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean ?

Comment: @John3136 I eddited the question. Didn't realise my code automactically turn to text

Comment: You can't make a vector of references, that just doesn't work.  You could try a vector of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

With C++20 you can achieve that with the following:

```
template<std::derived_from<Base> T>
void function(const std::vector<T>& v) {}
```

The above is using templates to accommodate any type of vector (by allowing the function to accept `const std::vector<T>&` where `T` is a template parameter). But to restrict T to be only derived of Base we add inside the template the restriction on T, requiring it to be `std::derived_from<Base>`.

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8aaa0c941fdc493e

---

Before C++20 it would require some more cumbersome [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>>* Dummy = nullptr>
void function(const std::vector<T>& v) {}
```

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b7d98a84b6139b7

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can pass both `vector<Sub1>` and `vector<Sub2>` into a function by using a reference to `vector<Base>`:

```
void Function(vector<Base>& v) {}
```

This should work because Sub1 and Sub2 are derived classes from Base, and a reference to a derived class can be passed to a reference to its base class. However, the function will not be able to modify the objects in the vector as the objects are passed by reference to a const vector.

Comment: I'm not sure that this would work. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: @Kimbo I think my example code confused you.  The actual class im dealing with have some string property so the vector is not const-qualified. My bad